# How can I change primary duplication error to message box in window form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, window

How can I change primary duplication error to message box in window form.

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click


    Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Guest( GuestName, CarModel, PlateNumber, PhoneNumber,ParkingLocation) VALUES('" & TextBoxGName.Text & "','" & TextBoxCarModel.Text & "','" & TextBoxPlateNum.Text & "','" & TextBoxPhoneNum.Text & "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "')"

    ExecuteQuery(insertQuery)


    MessageBox.Show("New Guest Added")






End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to refactor that ExecuteQuery method you wrote since it doesn't accommodate for parameters.  Your query is open to SQL injection attacks and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Try...Catch option and also send the innermost exception as the message.

```
Try
    Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Guest( GuestName, CarModel, PlateNumber, PhoneNumber,ParkingLocation) VALUES('" & TextBoxGName.Text & "','" & TextBoxCarModel.Text & "','" & TextBoxPlateNum.Text & "','" & TextBoxPhoneNum.Text & "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "')"

    ExecuteQuery(insertQuery)


    MessageBox.Show("New Guest Added")

Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, GetInnerMostException(ex).ToString)
End Try


 Public Function GetInnerMostException(ByVal ex As Exception) As Exception
    Dim exOut As Exception = ex
    Try
        While exOut.InnerException IsNot Nothing
            exOut = exOut.InnerException
        End While
    Catch e As Exception
        Return ex
    End Try

    Return exOut
End Function
```

Comment: I would refactor the V6-style `MsgBox` to a .NET `MessageBox`.

Comment: Yes, old habits die hard!